# Trouble creating environments in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda3

I am using this program for the first time and following a step-by-step plan I found on GitHub for the use of Megadetector. I've cloned the repos I needed to clone ad they've all been stored in a git folder.

I've followed the code for creating an environment, but it simply shows a loading symbol when the "Solving environments" prompt pops up.
Here's the code to set up the environmnet:

```
mkdir c:\git 
cd c:\git 
git clone https://github.com/ecologize/yolov5/ 
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/cameratraps 
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/ai4eutils 
cd c:\git\cameratraps conda env create --file environment-detector.yml 
conda activate cameratraps-detector set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;c:\git\cameratraps;c:\git\ai4eutils;c:\git\yolov5
```

This was produced by the last bit of code:

```
(base) c:\git\cameratraps>conda env create --file environment-detector.yml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: /
```

and this is as far as I have gotten with this set up. I know sometimes things just need to run but this is ridiculous. If anyone has any solutions to this issue please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Something you could try is enable conda-forge channel:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

Also, make sure conda is updated:

```
conda update conda
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I updated it now and then ran the add channels and forge code you sent and it gave me the following lines: Traceback (most recent call last):
  it then listed a bunch of file sites and then the following message:
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the whole error message ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you eventually fixed this issue, but FYI, in part because of these obscenely long solve times, the [updated MegaDetector instructions](https://github.com/agentmorris/MegaDetector/blob/main/megadetector.md) recommend using MambaForge rather than Anaconda.  If you are still experiencing this issue, please delete your copy of the repo, and try following the new instructions:

https://github.com/agentmorris/MegaDetector/blob/main/megadetector.md#using-the-model

If you are still having trouble when following the current instructions, please [file an issue](https://github.com/agentmorris/MegaDetector/issues).

Sorry for the hassle!